# Can I add more diskspace for extra use?

Tags: disk, disk-usage

Am I able to add more disk space to the OS?  I did the default during the install, and wondering in case I ever needed to allocate more.

Comment: Please provide more details. If I understood you, maybe you should read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Answer (score 0):

If you used LVM then you can add directly to the volume group and then logical volume in turn.

If you didn't use LVM, you can mount the new space in an existing directory. This will make the space available under that directory, but won't expand the space it has been mounted onto.